# Deploy rails app to heroku crashed but working fine in local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is my first time trying to use heroku to deploy. As it's build app already on heroku and not working 
 [It shows this error on the view and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuItd.png)

When i try to run  heroku logs --tail. It shows the following error.

```
2018-09-05T08:34:50.778080+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=project-x-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=805ce93c-2b60-426f-bcb8-575428a6affc fwd="118.173.233.9" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-05T08:34:51.610636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=project-x-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=7de53f2d-7310-4ec2-9a07-cfefae8f7ddc fwd="118.173.233.9" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Full logs here**

```
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709165+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709213+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709261+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709362+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709308+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709412+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709463+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709520+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709569+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709616+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709664+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709758+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709711+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709817+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709962+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710009+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710056+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709865+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.709913+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710103+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710151+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710198+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710251+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710300+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710347+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
2018-09-05T09:41:08.710422+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
2018-09-05T09:41:09.213725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=project-x-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=cb647327-8c03-4fde-bac0-012a9868e6d1 fwd="118.173.233.9" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=228 protocol=https
2018-09-05T09:44:45.700672+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 118.173.233.9 at 2018-09-05 09:44:45 +0000
2018-09-05T09:44:45.702908+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2018-09-05T09:44:45.741007+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms
2018-09-05T09:44:45.742704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-05T09:44:45.742751+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::LoadError (Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).):
2018-09-05T09:44:45.742818+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-05T09:44:45.742858+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:176:in `rescue in spec'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.742894+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:173:in `spec'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.742934+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743003+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743051+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743102+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743163+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743195+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743236+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743267+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743338+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743372+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743400+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743585+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743587+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743589+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:36:in `append_info_to_payload'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743591+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:36:in `ensure in block in process_action'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743593+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:36:in `block in process_action'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743595+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743652+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743693+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743732+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743893+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743896+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743899+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743901+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743907+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.743940+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744013+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744048+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744083+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744120+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744198+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744227+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744308+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744363+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744396+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744440+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744548+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744469+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744578+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744615+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744679+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744722+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744759+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744795+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744882+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744889+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744929+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.744965+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745146+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745148+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745150+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745152+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745153+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745159+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745368+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745371+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745373+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745374+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745376+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745382+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745414+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745448+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745486+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
2018-09-05T09:44:45.745555+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
2018-09-05T09:44:46.110843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=project-x-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=551b54be-bd1e-4b57-b75e-7580c573024d fwd="118.173.233.9" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=228 protocol=https
```

The following is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0'

gem 'font-awesome-rails'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.11', '>= 1.11.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'

end
```

Please help me to find out to solve this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you take a look at `heroku logs -t` and see what the actual error is. You will have to paste the entire log here. If that is not going to help, can you try this command `heroku restart`.

Comment: when i tried `heroku logs --tail` it shows the above error. I try `heroku restart` cmd too ... it's doesn't help. So i tried `heroku run rails console` then it shows that **Stack level too deep(systemStackError)***

Comment: The error means, there could be infinite loops that is causing the stack overflows

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna , I don't have any loops yet ... I just finish the views.

Comment: What version of `ruby` and `rails` are you using ?

Comment: I see you're using 2.4.0 and 4.2.5, either downgrade the version of ruby or update the rails version.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna `gem 'rails', '4.2.5'` & `rails 2.3.1`

Comment: Can you change the version of rails to `4.2.8`

Comment: As per your logs, in ruby 2.4 both `Fixnum` and `Bignum` are deprecated and referred to as `Integer`, which could be incompatible with your existing gems.

Comment: I upgrade my rails version heroku error page changed to **Somethings wents wrongs** **Check the error logs**

Comment: can you remove the old logs and paste the error you are seeing in the logs and format it please.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna ... yes ... already please check

Comment: What is your version of `Rails` now ? Did you update it to `5.0.0` ?

Comment: yes @KedarnagMukanahallipatna  .... after i update also local is fine

Comment: The error says you're missing `pg` gem, can you add that to your `Gemfile` and deploy again. if you have already have `pg` in `Gemfile`, I suggest you update it.

Comment: I've had to downvote this question. No reply from the OP.

Comment: @DickieBoy  what do u mean no reply ... i am way back home so how could i reply .... OMG

Comment: What is version of `pg` ?

Comment: I just installed pg like this not mentioned the version 

`group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end`

Answer (score 0):

I edited the post to format the logs correctly.

Heroku uses postgres for its databases, AFAIK this is non negotiable.

It appears you don't have the `pg` gem installed.

Comment: I installed like this 
`group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end`

Comment: @Htoo post your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock into the original question.

Comment: Can you check the `RAILS_ENV` on your heroku environment.

Comment: How to check that ?

Comment: Its a local variable. Open a console on heroku. Then type: `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`. Alternatively i think its local variable config for heroku.

Comment: I'm new to heroku too .... can you explain me step by step ... as how to open a console on heroku :(

Comment: `heroku run rails console` You did it yesterday, its in one of your other comments.

Comment: yes ... i run it. it says i didn't put the gem 'pg' but it's there already

Comment: Try and remove the group constraint around the pg gem. This might be one for heroku to answer.

Comment: It fixed by declearing ruby version but all the images and javascripts are not working ....

Comment: ` ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        Removing `vendor/bundle`.
remote:        Checking in `vendor/bundle` is not supported. Please remove this directory
remote:        and add it to your .gitignore. To vendor your gems with Bundler, use
remote:        `bundle pack` instead.
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server` 

**I got two warning**

Comment: Please upvote to my question. You also help me a lot ... i have another question so .. i would be posted as another question

Comment: Please unmark this as the correct answer. It isn't the correct answer. If you have found the correct answer. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes sure ..m i thought after i add the ruby version in gemfile its work

Answer (score 0):

You're missing Postgres, which is what Heroku uses / needs.
To get it working (quick-and-dirty style), add Postgres to the production block in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

And move the default sqlite 3 gem into a development / test block:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And re-push to Heroku.

This means you'll be running a Postgres DB on Heroku, and sqlite3 DB locally.

However, *ideally* you want to be running the same DB in all environments, in which case you'll have to install and run Postgres locally.

Comment: I’ve added ... i will show u when i get home .. reply u soon .. thanks

Comment: `group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
end`

`group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'

end` 

**This is what i did.**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of above comments and try to figure out for me. 
As I am new to the Rails and Heroku. I didn't know what I am doing and I'm still trying to understand the structure and other stuffs. To fix this Problem. What I added is i just add ,

ruby '2.3.1'

in my Gemfile. After I added that It fix but. All the CSS are not working on heroku.